# logm function of hermitian matrix returns non-hermitian matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

When I use the linear algebra module in scipy to calculate the matrix logarithm of a **hermitian matrix**, the matrix that it outputs isn't hermitian. I first define a vector using:

```
n = np.random.uniform(size = 3) + 1j*np.random.uniform(size = 3)
```

Then I define the respective hermitian matrix:

```
N = np.outer(n,n.conj())
```

However, `linalg.logm(N)` doesn't return a **hermitian matrix**. Why is this happening?

Comment: `N` is not a matrix when I run this code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant np.random.uniform(size = 3). I've corrected the OP.

Comment: Your matrix is singular; in fact, it has rank 1.  It doesn't have a logarithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All but one eigenvalues of the random matrix are zero. Since functions on matrices can be written as functions on the eigenvalues of a matrix, I see why the logarithm has a problem there, because log(0) is not defined. Maybe the function doesn't see this problem and just returns garbage.

I guess that you just need to make sure that your random Hermitian matrix has nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: And to the question why the result is not Hermitian: the algorithm used in logm here is not written in a way that it preserves hermiticity as an exact property. Since the input matrix is at a singular point, due to rounding error the result corresponds to the logm of some matrix eps-close to the input matrix. Since hermiticity is not exactly preserved, the eps-close matrix is usually non-hermitian. Now, a good question would be: *Why is the error estimate computed in `funm(N, np.log, disp=0)` not accurate in this case?*

Comment: Yes, I shall try that. Thank you!